# Apache rewriterule with serendipity weblog does not work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the serendipity weblog and want to make a rewriterule in an apache htaccess-file that when /info is being opened in the browser it opens /index.php?/categories/1-Info instead.

I tried following rewriterule:

```
RewriteRule ^info index.php?/categories/2-Info [L]
```

and it does not work. When I change the substitution into something else (like http://www.google.com) it does go there, so the pattern should work, but it doesn't show me the serendipity category that I want to see. The address does work though, when I enter it manually.

I read a dozen webpages with guides and used "http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/" to verify my rewriterule, but I still cannot get it to work. Unfortunately I cannot see or set any logging either.

How do I have to change the rewriterule?

Edit:

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN s9y
ErrorDocument 404 /data/script/index.php
DirectoryIndex /data/script/index.php
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /data/script/
RewriteRule ^info index.php?/categories/2-Info [L]

<Files *.tpl.php>
    deny from all
</Files>

<Files *.tpl>
    deny from all
</Files>

<Files *.sql>
    deny from all
</Files>

<Files *.inc.php>
    deny from all
</Files>

<Files *.db>
    deny from all
</Files>

# END s9y
```

Comment: Where is your htaccess file? Are there other rules?

Comment: I added the htaccess file. There are no other rules in it.

Answer (score 5):

Try forcing an external redirect by adding the `R` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^info index.php?/categories/2-Info [L,R]
```